# How do can I detect that the Small app is active?

Tags: android, tablet, sony

How do can I detect that the Small app is active?

Mini app package name
com.sony.nfx.app.plusone.calculator
Is.

In getRunningTasks,
I believe you can get a list of apps that you have started.

However, the mini-app is not subject to.

In getRunningTasks,
Have not been able to get the package name of the mini-application that you have started.

I want to make the detection of mini apps.
If there is any good way, please tell me.

**

> I is not to simply get a list of processes. I want to detect the fact
>   that the user has started to operate.

**

Thank you.

**sony tablet S
Android 4.0.3**

**android java code**

```
public void run_task_log(){


       ArrayList<String> appList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);


        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processList = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for(RunningAppProcessInfo process : processList) {
            //Log.i(TAG,"pid:"+process.pid);
            //Log.i(TAG,"processName:"+process.processName);
            appList.add(   (String) "" + process.pid + ":" +process.processName);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, appList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);








        List<RunningTaskInfo> taskList = activityManager.getRunningTasks(10);
        for(RunningTaskInfo task : taskList) {
            Log.d("ActivityManager","task.topActivity.getPackageName():"+task.topActivity.getPackageName());
        }
        List<RunningServiceInfo> serviceList = activityManager.getRunningServices(30);
        for(RunningServiceInfo serv : serviceList) {
            Log.d("ActivityManager","PID:"+serv.pid+":serv.getPackageName():"+serv.service.getPackageName());
            Log.d("ActivityManager","PID:"+serv.pid+":serv.clientPackage():"+serv.clientPackage);
        }




        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        ActivityManager activityManager1 = ((ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE));
        List<RunningTaskInfo> runningTask = activityManager1.getRunningTasks(100);
        ArrayList<CharSequence> activityNameList = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
        if (runningTask != null) {
            for (RunningTaskInfo task : runningTask) {
                try {
                    Log.d("ActivityManager","packageManager.getApplicationLabel():"+packageManager.getApplicationLabel(packageManager.getApplicationInfo(task.topActivity.getPackageName(), 0)));
                } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
                }
            }
        }




        ActivityManager activityManager2 = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Service.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        String className = activityManager.getRunningTasks(3).get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
        Log.d("ActivityManager","className:"+className);


}
```

**Logcat Log**

```
    12-11 16:53:36.360: D/T2MDMService(3775): ////// ID Service Timer Start ///
12-11 16:53:36.370: D/ActivityManager(3775): task.topActivity.getPackageName():com.sony.nfx.app.launcher2
12-11 16:53:36.370: D/ActivityManager(3775): task.topActivity.getPackageName():com.anetm.www.apprunlist
12-11 16:53:36.380: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:434:serv.getPackageName():com.android.smspush
12-11 16:53:36.380: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:434:serv.clientPackage():null
12-11 16:53:36.380: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:2996:serv.getPackageName():com.sony.nfx.app.plusone.calculator
12-11 16:53:36.380: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:2996:serv.clientPackage():null
12-11 16:53:36.380: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:3174:serv.getPackageName():com.android.providers.media
12-11 16:53:36.380: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:3174:serv.clientPackage():null
12-11 16:53:36.380: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:3534:serv.getPackageName():com.sony.nfx.hwmonitorservice
12-11 16:53:36.390: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:3534:serv.clientPackage():null
12-11 16:53:36.390: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:313:serv.getPackageName():com.google.android.location
12-11 16:53:36.390: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:313:serv.clientPackage():null
12-11 16:53:36.390: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:0:serv.getPackageName():com.google.android.talk
12-11 16:53:36.390: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:0:serv.clientPackage():null
12-11 16:53:36.390: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:3522:serv.getPackageName():com.sony.nfx.app.wappushdbinit
12-11 16:53:36.390: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:3522:serv.clientPackage():null
12-11 16:53:36.390: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:249:serv.getPackageName():com.android.systemui
12-11 16:53:36.390: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:249:serv.clientPackage():null
12-11 16:53:36.390: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:3508:serv.getPackageName():com.sony.automagic.blservice
12-11 16:53:36.390: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:3508:serv.clientPackage():null
12-11 16:53:36.390: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:313:serv.getPackageName():com.google.android.location
12-11 16:53:36.390: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:313:serv.clientPackage():null
12-11 16:53:36.390: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:2984:serv.getPackageName():com.sony.smallapp.plusoneservice
12-11 16:53:36.390: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:2984:serv.clientPackage():null
12-11 16:53:36.390: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:328:serv.getPackageName():com.sony.nfx.inputmethod
12-11 16:53:36.400: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:328:serv.clientPackage():android
12-11 16:53:36.400: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:375:serv.getPackageName():com.android.stk
12-11 16:53:36.400: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:375:serv.clientPackage():null
12-11 16:53:36.400: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:167:serv.getPackageName():com.google.android.backup
12-11 16:53:36.400: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:167:serv.clientPackage():null
12-11 16:53:36.400: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:375:serv.getPackageName():com.android.phone
12-11 16:53:36.400: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:375:serv.clientPackage():null
12-11 16:53:36.400: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:375:serv.getPackageName():com.mbm.mbmservice
12-11 16:53:36.400: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:375:serv.clientPackage():null
12-11 16:53:36.400: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:249:serv.getPackageName():com.android.systemui
12-11 16:53:36.400: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:249:serv.clientPackage():android
12-11 16:53:36.400: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:3495:serv.getPackageName():com.sony.automagic.ui
12-11 16:53:36.400: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:3495:serv.clientPackage():null
12-11 16:53:36.400: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:313:serv.getPackageName():com.google.android.gsf
12-11 16:53:36.400: D/ActivityManager(3775): PID:313:serv.clientPackage():null
12-11 16:53:36.400: D/ActivityManager(3775): packageManager.getApplicationLabel():ホーム
12-11 16:53:36.400: D/ActivityManager(3775): packageManager.getApplicationLabel():AppRunList
12-11 16:53:36.410: D/ActivityManager(3775): className:com.android.launcher2.Launcher
12-11 16:53:36.410: D/T2MDMService(3775): ////// ID Service Timer End ///
```

Comment: I dont understand what is a mini app? I dont understand your question

Comment: Thank you very much.
It's the SONY Tablet S,

http://ctec3.blog.so-net.ne.jp/2012-03-28
Small application to its nickname, the topic in (mini-applications),

There is here such as a calculator (separate package)
This app is a small calculator (mini-applications) are being displayed on the front always starts,

If you launch the app other common application is a small calculator (mini applications) is a remain in the front.

Comment: I'd like to detect that this app is a small calculator (mini application) is activated,

In what way was to get so far, the foreground app did not work,

We are looking for or have no way to detect something.
What there is no way ... something.
Thank you.

Comment: I think maybe when you refer to mini-app you mean Widget in Android terminology?

Comment: the -- mini -- an application is the application of the third party of the other company which cannot be predicted. 
I would like to be active and to detect that the focus is carried out. 
http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/tool-guides/sony-tablet-sdk-add-on/small-apps/

Comment: I could not actually understand what 'activeness', do you want to check. Do you want to check if the small app is on foreground or specifically calculator is launched as a small app? - Anupam Nath, Sony Mobile Developer Program